# Vuejs component is not loaded by using webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ProductEdit from './ProductEdit.vue'
import App from 'components/App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#page',
  components: {
    'app': App
  },
  render: h => h(ProductEdit)
})
```

Why is `ProductEdit` rendered, but `App` is not?
Here's my html file:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

<div id="page">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <app>

    </app>
</div>

{% render_bundle page %}
```

Moreover, the "TEST" header is also not rendered. How can I debug this? The console doesn't show any errors.

EDIT:
I also tried without render function and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) replaces the template contents of the specified `el` (i.e., the `#page` element in this case). If you prefer to use in-DOM templates (which appears to be the case), you'd have to remove the render function:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#page',
  // render: /* ... */    // DELETE
})
```

I'm assuming you want `App` to contain `ProductEdit`. To do that, register the `ProductEdit` component in `App`:

```
// App.vue
export default {
  components: {
     ProductEdit,
  },
})
```

...and add the element in `App`'s template:

```
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <product-edit />
  </div>
<template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ywzvl6w0k9)

Comment: You are right, but this wasn't the problem. I also tried it withour render function and didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What was the error/behavior you saw?

Comment: The error was the same, nothing was rendered. I post the answer with solution in my case.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how that Webpack would be the cause of the original problem, but I'm glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it. The problem was that I redefine resolve property in `webpack.config.js`, which override default resolve generated via vue cli:

```
...

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
...

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
    },
  },
```

So I merge it into:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
```